# Convert string to date type in Athena AWS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-date-functions, amazon-athena

I have a column that called date with the following format : '20220816'
how can I convert this column into Date format?

I tried to use this function : date_parse(date,'%y/%m/%d')  but it keep giving me this error:
NVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "20220627" is malformed at "220627"

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the slashes from your query. Below query convert it to date format for you. Just replace the string with the column containing values

```
select cast(date_parse('20220816','%Y%m%d') as date)
```